# Unable to Access SAP Fiori Application - Error: 403 Forbidden

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have been trying out the Freestyle SAP Fiori Project and Deployed it to my Sub Account Space. It is Deployed Successfully and it is in a running state. However, when I try to access it, it says "403 Forbidden".

**Screenshot 1: Error Message while Accessing the App**

[image: SAP Fiori App]

**Screenshot 2: App Status**

[image: App Status]

**#Update 1:** Roles, Scope, Role Templates are Empty

I went inside the deployed Application to see its Roles, Scopes & Role Templates. But all of them are empty. Can this be the reason? If yes, how do we assign them?

**#Update 2:** Roles, Scope, Role Templates are Empty

I have verified the MTAR Archive to see whether xs-security.json file is getting included and I can confirm it is getting included. For example, below is the content of that file.

**xs-security.json**

```
{
  "xsappname": "demofiori",
  "tenant-mode": "dedicated",
  "description": "Security profile of called application",
  "scopes": [
    {
      "name": "uaa.user",
      "description": "UAA"
    }
  ],
  "role-templates": [
    {
      "name": "Token_Exchange",
      "description": "UAA",
      "scope-references": [
        "uaa.user"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: App Security Settings]

Comment: is it a trial or productive CF account?

Comment: Its a Trial Account

Comment: I believe I had faced similar issue long time back. If my memory serves well, it was related to xsuaa ... can you check that the relevant artifacts e.g. xs-security.json are present in your MTA? Check this [Blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/08/20/demystifying-xsuaa-in-sap-cloud-foundry/)

Comment: @Swadhin, I have verified the MTAR Archive file and it contains the xs-security.json file with right content. I have given the content of that file above.